# RXJS show error after takes

Tags: angular, rxjs

In Angular 2 I use rxjs to do my HTTP calls. Currently it is setup to display errors as follows.

```
this.http.get("http://www.someapifunction.com/api" , {headers: headers, params: data})
.map(res => res.json())
    .subscribe(
      data => { 
          console.log(data);
      },
      err => {
        console.log('error',err);
        this.showError(err);  
      },
      () => console.log('Request Complete')
    );
```

If there is an error the code will run a function which shows an error message.

What I now trying to do is implement rxjs retryWhen + take to run the code 2 times before printing an error message. As below:

```
this.http.get("http://www.someapifunction.com/api" , {headers: headers, params: data})
.readyWhen(errors => errors.delay(5000).take(2))
.map(res => res.json())
    .subscribe(
      data => { 
          console.log(data);
      },
      err => {
        console.log('error',err);
        this.showError(err);  
      },
      () => console.log('Request Complete')
    );
```

The issue I have is once take the API has retried unsuccessfully twice it does not run the err function. What do I need to do so that it does run the err function ie this.showErr(err)??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `retryWhen` every `next` notification means it tries to resubscribe to its source Observable. Any `complete` and `error` notifications are just passed further. So what you want to do is that when you've already made two attempts you just want to send the error further.

The errors are passed into the Observable returned from `retryWhen`s callback as `next` notifications so you want to conditionally turn them into `error`.

You can do it for example like this:

```
.retryWhen(errors => errors
  .map((err, index) => {
    if (index === 2) {
      throw err;
    }
    return err;
  })
  .delay(5000))
```

Comment: Thank you for this I will give it a go!